# overriding subclasses in actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Trying to find a straight answer for this. I am going to be creating some sub classes in actionscript 3. I was wanting to know if it is possible to override the parent class. If so, do I need to put a override assigner on the parent class method or what.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override any non-private method in your subclass.

And there is no keyword to indicate in the base class whether a method can or has to be overridden (like virtual in C++).

```
E.g.

public class A
{
  public function methodOfA():void
  {
  }
}

public class B extends A
{
  override public function methodOfA():void
  {
    // do something more specific to B
  }
}
```

Comment: NB: You can override any non-private method or property that is not marked as `final`

Comment: can you override event handlers ??